# Scripting Shell Settings

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe

I really hate manually setting up cmd and powershell cmd shell properties like window height/width, font, coloring, enabling Quick Edit.

Doe anyone know if there a script I can run to set things up the way I want when entering a new server or workstation?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where are the default settings saved for the Command prompt defaults?](http://superuser.com/questions/683431/where-are-the-default-settings-saved-for-the-command-prompt-defaults)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: [Where are the default settings saved for the Command prompt defaults?](https://superuser.com/questions/683431/where-are-the-default-settings-saved-for-the-command-prompt-defaults)

Export the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console registry folder to a .reg file, and then you can easily import them by double-clicking on the file.  To automate the import, run `regedit /s c:\temp\console.reg` and the registry file will be imported automatically.

On my Windows 7 system this registry key controls both cmd and Powershell settings.