# Where are places other than HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console that cmd.exe stores colors?

Tags: command-line, colors

I've imported a color scheme into my registry at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console`

Now when I hit <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, and go to `Command Prompt (Admin)` I see my nice color scheme.

If I navigate to `cmd.exe` and open it manually, I see my nice color scheme.

BUT, if I open up <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, and go to `Command Prompt` (not admin) I see the lame old black and white colors... No nice scheme.

I tried to delete link file at `C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WinX\Group3` and re-create it by copying and modifying the Admin lnk, but still, no nice color scheme.

I've tried importing the colors to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Command Processor`, too, with no luck.

I also tried opening the prompt and typing `color` (and `COLOR`)... No dice.

What's annoying is that if I click the logo in the top left, and click "Defaults" -- then I see the color scheme is in the settings... But it's not what is rendered in the terminal.

I tried rebooting, too.. No dice.

Does anyone know where else these colors might be coming from -- and why only from that one link?

Comment: `If I navigate to cmd.exe` Which one? There are two of them, under System32 and SysWow64 respectively. Also, I assume you looked at the subkeys of HKCU\Console as well, where per-app settings are saved, including colors.

Comment: Both cmd.exe's -- System32 and SysWow64 use the correct color scheme. The process is identical to what the link points to, but when started from the link the color is incorrect. I did look at subkeys -- there is no subkey for that <kbd>Windows key</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> link

Comment: `I tried to delete link file at C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WinX\Group3 and re-create it` Make sure to create a *console app* shortcut i.e. one which has the console options, including `colors`, available. If in doubt, you can copy the `.lnk` files from `C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WinX\Group3` and edit the colors. Just tried it on Windows 10 and it works for me.

Comment: I tried that, by copying the Admin lnk. The behavior is crazy to me. It works as expected, but if I rename the new link to the old name, `02 - Command Prompt.lnk` then it goes back to the stupid boring black/white colors... If I rename it back to `01-2 - Command Prompt.lnk`, then I get my nice colors. I searched the entire registry for that name `02 - Command Prompt` but couldn't find anything related to colors. I have a 32-bit ASUS and did not encounter this issue. This is on a  64 bit HP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks to be a change in Windows 10 vs. the behavior described by @JosefZ for Windows 8.x.

The 2 shortcuts executed for <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> `Command Prompt` exist in the same place, with the same names (`01` is the Admin one):

```
C:\>dir /b %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\WinX\Group3\*command*.*
01 - Command Prompt.lnk
02 - Command Prompt.lnk
```

However, running/customizing either <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> `Command Prompt` no longer saves the console options to the `HKCU\Console` registry, but rather saves them (only) to the `.lnk` shortcut itself.

The solution in this case is to navigate in Windows Explorer to `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WinX\Group3` and, for each of the two `.lnk` shortcuts, right click, select `Properties`, click the `Colors` tab and fix the colors. Or, simply replace the default `.lnk` shortcuts with a `cmd` shortcut that you have set to the right color scheme already.

Comment: Yes this is basically what I had to do. But what's really crazy is that somehow the name `02 - Command Prompt.lnk` keeps an association to the old color scheme. So in addition to your answer, I have to rename the link, and then adjust the pointer to the link name in the `LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\WinX\Group3\.desktop.ini` file

Comment: Hmm I tried renaming it again and now it works with the original name! I did a search on the `user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows` directory for that name, and it turned up in `user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\.\Caches\{AFBF91A-.......}.....db` -- I bet there was some association to the file name cached in that `.db` file.

Comment: I have a `.bat` file that I use to quickly SSH. Turns out, similar to the `.lnk` files, all the Command Prompt Properties (not Defaults) that were configured in the Command Prompt, specific to that opening of the `.bat` file, got stored "in" the file itself. If I right-click on the file and go to its similarly named Properties, then there are tabs for things like Colours.

Comment: @Cloud The console preferences get saved in either the registry or the `.lnk` shortcut, though not in the `.bat` file itself. It's easy to verify that if you copy the batch file to a different machine, the configured properties do not carry over.

Comment: @dxiv Ah alright, then maybe it was buried somewhere in the registry as subkeys. Couldn't find it though, and those preferences were specific to that launching of the bat file under that name.

Answer (score 1):

Values under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console` store *default* command prompt settings. However, anyone can customize appearance of different command prompt windows launched from different shortcuts; settings are stored in *subkeys* of the `HKCU\Console` registry keys: see full description in [console-window-name](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957408.aspx) Technet article. 
A particular subkey is updated when you change corresponding shortcut properties (tabs `Options`, `Font`, `Layout` and `Colours`).  The same for currently open command prompt window **properties** (not *defaults*) on window top border <kbd>right click</kbd>.

Shortcuts for command prompt launched via <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> could be found here: `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\WinX\Group3`

For instance, on **my** Windows 8.1:

```
==> dir /B "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\WinX\Group3"|find /i "Command"
01 - Command Prompt.lnk
02 - Command Prompt.lnk

==> reg query HKCU\Console |find /I "\Console" |find /V /I "PowerShell"
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%SystemRoot%_System32_cmd.exe
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\01 - Command Prompt
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\02 - Command Prompt
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\Command Prompt
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\Command Prompt X

==>
```

Here individual `HKCU\Console` subkeys correspond to next command prompt shortcuts:

- `%SystemRoot%_System32_cmd.exe`: <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>`cmd /D` or (not sure) <kbd>WinKey</kbd>`cmd`
- `01 - Command Prompt`: <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>Command Prompt (Admin)
- `02 - Command Prompt`: <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>Command Prompt
- `Command Prompt`: shortcut from Start menu search (<kbd>WinKey</kbd>`Command Prompt`) pinned to taskbar
- `Command Prompt X`: special shortcut on *my* desktop.

**Edit with respect to [tmsimont's](https://superuser.com/users/86168/tmsimont) comment**: maybe that there is a mistake in my pristine description and when you run a particular shortcut, then corresponding subkey is **not created** and *defaults* are used for launched command window…

However, a [particular subkey  of the `HKCU\Console` registry key](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957408.aspx) is created/updated when you save changes to corresponding shortcut properties (tabs `Options`, `Font`, `Layout` and `Colours`).  The same for currently open command prompt window **properties** (not *defaults*) on window top border <kbd>right click</kbd>.

Comment: I see subkeys, but not one for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\02 - Command Prompt` which would be the link that is acting up on me... I even tried deleting all of the keys and subkeys in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console`, and then importing only my new color scheme. It still doesn't make this link work properly.