# Can't open command prompt or run any .bat files

Tags: windows, windows-10, cmd.exe

On my Windows 10 PC I'm trying to open a command prompt but nothing happens, regardless of how I try to do it. Trying from the start menu, from the actual .exe in `C:\Windows`, from Win+X menu, etc. Nothing works. I also can't run any .bat files. Powershell works properly, but if I try to run a .bat file in Powershell, nothing happens again.

Additionally, running `cmd` from Powershell prints

> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3324]
> (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

but doesn't open a command prompt instance, just immediately terminates the command (no error message is printed to Powershell). Likewise, if I run `cmd /C echo hi` in Powershell, nothing is printed and no command prompt instance is created.

I've tried various disk-checking solutions and the like, such as `sfc`, `chkdsk` and similar, and I'm running a full virus scan at the moment, however none of these have been successful.

Short of reinstalling Windows, what else can I try in order to restore cmd functionality?

Comment: 'cd' is Change Directory, and doesn't check the disk. There are Windows 10 repair commands using DISM (https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-dism-command-line-utility-repair-windows-10-image). Your Windows install is likely corrupted and you need to try a repair.

Comment: Is the reason you are running cmd from a PowerShell prompt, because, launching Command Prompt from the start menu does not work?

Comment: If you install and use Windows Terminal to launch a Command Prompt window does the behavior still exhibit itself? I suspect this is a file association issue.

Comment: See if `CMD /D` in PowerShell (or the Start box) works better. If so you, or some software you ran/allowed, set an 'autorun' command for CMD.exe that either intentionally exits or malfunctions in some way that causes an exit. See https://superuser.com/questions/683431/where-are-the-default-settings-saved-for-the-command-prompt-defaults#683450 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404165/how-to-run-a-command-on-command-prompt-startup-in-windows

Comment: @music2myear sorry, I meant `chkdsk`, not `cd` (edited the question now). I've also tried running DISM now (`Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth`), but it just says `No component store corruption detected.`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 yes, `cmd /d` works fine. I guess I'll need to find something in the autoruns that's causing the issues.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, I've managed to locate the issue. The key `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun` contained the text `if exist`, ostensibly as a leftover of something I installed at some point. Deleting this key restored the cmd functionality. Feel free to type up an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @dave_thompson_085's comment, I tried to run

```
cmd /d
```

in Powershell. This worked properly (i.e. it launched a command prompt instance inside Powershell). The `/d` switch turns off autorun for the `cmd` command, implying that I had something in the autorun that caused the `cmd` invocation to fail.

Scanning through the linked answers ([1](https://superuser.com/questions/683431/where-are-the-default-settings-saved-for-the-command-prompt-defaults#683450) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404165/how-to-run-a-command-on-command-prompt-startup-in-windowsk)), I found that the registry key `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun` contained the nonsensical value `if exist`, ostensibly as a leftover of something I installed at some point. Deleting this key restored all `cmd` functionality.

Comment: Chat With RTX failure install can cause this problem - this is the fix

Answer (score 3):

1. A bad value in an environment variable could cause the issue. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>Pause/Break</kbd> to open *System Settings*. Go to *Advanced system settings* to open *System Properties* dialog. Click *Environment Variables* to open that dialog.

   - Check that the System variable `ComSpec` is set to `%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe`.
   - An error in PATH effectively disables *everything* subsequent to it. Examine PATH in both User and System variables for errors.
   - [Ten Computer](https://tencomputer.com/command-prompt-not-working-windows-10/) suggests creating an addition to **User** environment variable PATH of `C:\Windows\SysWow64\`.
2. Try creating a new User account to see if CMD works there. If so, it *might* also fix the issue in your normal account, according to [Ten Computer](https://tencomputer.com/command-prompt-not-working-windows-10/).
3. There is a [Group Policy (GPO) setting](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/enable-disable-command-prompt-windows) to disable use of CMD. Use the GPO Editor or Regedit to check if that restriction is enabled.

   - Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `rege` and select *Regedit*.
   - Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System`. If the value `DisableCMD` exists, double-click it and set to zero, `0`.

   *However*, when that policy is set, you should see the notice, "The command prompt has been disabled by your administrator," so this is likely *not* the issue.
4. Byte the bullet, so to speak, and reinstall Windows as from ISO created with the [MS installation media creation tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10/), as repair, *keeping files*. It is a good idea to make a disk image prior to doing so, lest something go wrong. My experience has been that this does not take more than an hour or two, and generally succeeds without damage.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe cmd.exe got overwritten somehow? For me on Window 11 it's at C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe and it's 316 KB. If you have another Windows machine perhaps you can copy it from there.

Also for me running cmd from Powershell prints out the same thing. One way to know if it actually launched cmd is the prompt. In PowerShell it's:

```
PS C:\>
```

In cmd it's:

```
C:\>
```

Perhaps you're in cmd but it's just not clear? In cmd you should be able to run `echo %PATH%` and have it expand to show your path variable. In PowerShell that command will just print "echo %PATH%".

Comment: Yeah, the prompt remains `PS C:\>` and `echo %PATH%` just prints `%PATH%`, so cmd is not launched. My cmd.exe (on Windows 10) is 283KB. However I'd expect something like `sfc` to repair a corrupted cmd.exe, no?

Comment: You'd think so, sorry I'm not sure what to do short of a Windows reinstall then.